# is ConcurrentHashMap.put() always Thread-Safe? if so, then why it is not working correctly?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I wrote a class (userRepository) including a method named init().
init method initializes ConcurrentHashMap, when I invoke this method in multiple threads (for example in three threads and in each thread for n times), I expect that the size of the map equals nx3. but it is not!
on the other hand, when I use ReentrantLock or synchronized keyword on the signature of the method it works perfectly fine. I mean the size of the map is equal to nx3.
please check the following example:

```
public class UserRepository implements CustomRepository<User, Integer> {
    private final Map<Integer, User> userMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private int index = 0;

    public void init() {
        userMap.put(index, new User("User_" + index).setId(index));
        index++;
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Integer id : userMap.keySet())
            userList.add(userMap.get(id));

        return userList;
    }
}
```

```
public class ChallengeApplication {
    static ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();

        int a = 5000000;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ex.submit(() -> {
            for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
                userRepository.init();
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " finished in " + time);
        });

        ex.submit(() -> {
            for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
                userRepository.init();
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " finished in " + time);
        });

        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
            userRepository.init();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " finished in " + time);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Size of map: " + userRepository.findAll().size());
    }
}
```

and this is the console output:

````
Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main] finished in 3832

Thread[main,5,main] finished in 3938

Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main] finished in 3996

Size of map: 14347920```
````

as you can see n=5000000 and there are 3 threads, so I expect that size of the pool equals  5000000*3= 15000000 but it is 13991739!

**I would like to know what is the reason for this conflict!?**

please note that when I put synchronize keyword or using ReentrantLock it works correctly

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap.put()` itself is thread-safe (it won't mess up if multiple threads call it concurrently), but it can ofcourse not make your own surrounding code thread-safe (for example, incrementing `index` etc.).

Comment: actually, I tried AtomicInteger instead of int, but nothing changed and still working in the wrong way, but you're right the whole method is not thread-safe, so what is the solution? if we're supposed to use synchronized keyword or ReentrantLock, we can use HashMap instead of ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: Two independent "threadsafe variables" used together does not make a threadsafe method/program.

Comment: @GaëlJ thank you, depending ConcurrentHashMap on another variable that is not thread-safe was my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the hash map itself but the index. You are using ++ which isn’t an atomic command and thus isn’t thread safe. When you are using synchronized word on the function it syncs the index too and solves the problem.

Comment: you mean if I use an AtomicInteger, instead of int, it should work fine right?
you are right index++ is not threadSafe but, I changed it to AtomicInteger and still working in a wrong way

Comment: Not alone, the problem is with the index between two threads. You need to lock it every time for each thread and only after creating the user and advancing the index, only then release the lock and without the lock you can add the user to the map and it doesn’t need to be a concurrent one

Comment: so you mean, as I mentioned in the question, I have to lock it somehow, either by adding synchronize or by lock/release mechanism. 
thank you, depending ConcurrentHashMap on another variable that is not thread-safe was my mistake.